# Query in SQL Server to have different name(for color) from each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make one query in sql with one field that have different name of color!

I need this because some program read that fiel color, is there some way to do this?

For example i have this query

```
select distinct ref from table
```

With this output!

```
ref
170015              
170103              
170118              
170120              
170157              
180002              
180004
```

And i need something like this

```
ref        color
170015      rgb(0,0,0)        
170103      rgb(0,0,125)        
170118      rgb(0,125,0)        
170120      rgb(125,0,0)        
170157      rgb(0,0,250)        
180002      rgb(0,250,0)       
180004      rgb(250,0,0)
...         ...
```

or

```
   ref        color
170015      0        
170103      8192000        
170118      32000        
170120      125        
170157      16384000        
180002      64000       
180004      250
...         ...
```

I need more or less than 30 different colors.

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: How do you get the color values?

Comment: It seems you merely want an additional table that contains one record per `ref` and has a column for the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a list of colour values in another table.

```
with prettycolours as
(
select colourvalue, row_number() over(order by uniqueidentifier) cn
from colours
)
, CTE as
(
select a1.ref, row_number() over (order by a1.ref) rn
from (select distinct ref from MyTable) a1
)
select ref, colourvalue
from CTE
inner join prettycolours
  on rn = cn
```

This only works if there are more colours than refs

If not, you'll need some remainder cleverness

```
with prettycolours as
(
select colourvalue, row_number() over(order by uniqueidentifier)-1 cn
from colours
)
, CTE as
(
select a1.ref, (select max(cn) from prettycolours) % row_number() over (order by a1.ref) rn
from (select distinct ref from MyTable) a1
)
select ref, colourvalue
from CTE
inner join prettycolours
  on rn = cn
```